# Different definitions of Bayes risk

Tags: bayesian, estimation, decision-theory, risk

I'm having trouble understanding the proper definition of Bayes risk.
Let the data/variate $x \sim P(X|\theta)$, $\theta\in \Theta$, $\pi$ be a  distribution on $\Theta$ (prior), $\hat \theta(x)$ be an estimator of $\theta$ based on a variates $x$, and $L$ a loss function between true and estimated parameters $\theta$.
It appears to me that there are two different notions of Bayes risk around:

1. For given data , the **Bayes risk** is defined as $$\mathbb{E}[L(\theta, \hat\theta(x)]$$ with the expectation taken over the prior $\pi$, and $x$ fixed. This is what you'll find in Wikipedia, for instance.
2. In function estimation like wavelet theory, and when contrasting Bayes and minimax estimation, the **risk**  is defined as $$R(\theta, \hat\theta) = \mathbb{E}[L(\theta, \hat\theta(x))]$$ where the expectation is taken over $P(X|\theta)$ (in regression, where $\theta$ is the signal, this means we integrate over the noise). For minimax estimation, we look at the **maximum risk** $$\max_{\theta\in\Theta} R(\theta, \hat\theta)$$ whereas for the **Bayes risk**, we put a prior $\pi$ in $\Theta$, so the Bayes risk is defined as $$\mathbb{E}[R(\theta, \hat\theta)]$$ with the expectation taken with respect to $\pi$.

So one is defined for a specific variate, using the loss function, whereas the other is defined for the expected loss (risk) across all variates. I was wondering if these are really two different things, or my understanding is off, or if they are two sides of the same thing. I would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: There's actually a 3rd one. In ML/Statistical Learning Theory, the Bayes risk is defined as $\arg\max_f\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[f(X) \not = Y]$, and the optimal $f^*$ is called the bayes classifier (see for eg. Devroye et al. 1996). Does anyone know why? Is it only by analogy to the case here (with $y$ replacing $\theta$)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To quote from my book, [The Bayesian Choice](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw) (2007, Section 2.3, pp. 63-64)

> The Bayesian approach to decision theory integrates on the parameter
> space $\Theta$, since $\theta$ is unknown, instead of integrating on
> the sampling space ${\cal X}$, as $x$ is observed. It relies on the
> ***posterior expected loss*** \begin{eqnarray*} \rho(\pi,d|x) & = &
>  \mathbb{E}^\pi[L(\theta,d)|x] \\ \tag{1}
>        & = & \int_{\Theta} \mathrm{L}(\theta,d) \pi(\theta|x)\, \text{d}\theta, \end{eqnarray*} which averages the error (i.e., the
> loss) according to the posterior distribution of the parameter
> $\theta$, conditional on the observed value $x$. Given $x$, the
> average error resulting from decision $d$ is actually $\rho(\pi,d|x)$.
> The posterior expected loss is thus a function of $x$ but this
> dependence is not an issue, as opposed to the frequentist dependence
> of the risk on the parameter because $x$, contrary to $\theta$, is known.
>
> Given a prior distribution $\pi$, it is also possible to define the
> ***integrated risk***, which is the frequentist risk averaged over the
> values of $\theta$ according to their prior distribution
> \begin{eqnarray*} r(\pi,\delta) & = & \mathbb{E}^\pi[R(\theta,\delta)]
>   \\ \tag{2}
>                 & = & \int_{\Theta} \int_{\cal X} \mathrm{L}(\theta,\delta(x))\,
>                      f(x|\theta) \,\text{d}x\ \pi(\theta)\, \text{d}\theta. \end{eqnarray*} One particular appeal of this second
> concept is that it associates a real number with every estimator, not
> a function of $\theta$. It therefore induces a total ordering on the
> set of estimator s, i.e., allows for the direct comparison of
> estimators. This implies that, while taking into account the prior
> information through the prior distribution, the Bayesian approach is
> sufficiently reductive (in a positive sense) to reach an
> effective decision. Moreover, the above two notions are equivalent in
> that they lead to the same decision.

A bit further, I use the following definition for the Bayes risk:

> A ***Bayes estimator***  associated with  a prior distribution $\pi$ and a loss
> function $\mathrm{L}$ is any estimator $\delta^\pi$ which minimizes
> $r(\pi,\delta)$. For every $x\in\cal{X}$, it is given by $\delta^\pi(x)$,
> argument of $$\min_d \rho(\pi,d|x)$$ The value $$r(\pi) =
>  r(\pi,\delta^\pi)\tag{3}$$ is then called the ***Bayes risk***.

Comment: Thanks! So to clarify: Bayes risk in 1. = your posterior expected loss, risk in 2. = your frequentist risk, Bayes risk in 2. = your integrated risk, and the risk attained by the minimizing (Bayes) estimator for 2. = your Bayes risk, correct? Also, is it true that $\delta^\pi$ always minimizes both globally as well as for each $x$, as you seem to imply?

Comment: Yes, this is a correct summary. And the Bayes estimate is found by minimising the posterior expected risk for each value of $x$, provided Fubini's theorem applies.

Comment: @Josh: I am afraid I do not see the link with empirical risk in either question or answer.

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an I just fixed the comment: Re-posting: this is a great answer (BTW I love your book!). QQ on the above, where does [Empirical risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization) fit above? I know it's a Monte Carlo approximation of a type of statistical risk, but which type?